# Can I print a numpy array's values in green if positive and red if negative?

Tags: python, numpy, colors

I'd like a quick visual cue when printing a numpy array of floats to console. How can I use colors to indicate positivity/negativity?

I've found this hacky way of changing the color of the console, but I'm not sure it's helpful in my case:

```
>>>YELLOW = '\033[93m'
>>>ENDCOLOR = '\033[0m'
>>>print(YELLOW+'hello'+ENDCOLOR)
hello # <-- this is yellow
>>>this is in your regular console color
```

but if you leave out the last string:

```
>>>YELLOW = '\033[93m'
>>>ENDCOLOR = '\033[0m'
>>>print(YELLOW+'hello')
hello #<-- it's yellow
>>>this is yellow as well, until you print ENDCOLOR
```

Comment: I think you will need to write a custom function that prints the array elements along with the required ANSI codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is to use the formatter kwarg in `np.set_printoptions` and colorama as suggested by Vikas Damodar:

```
import colorama
import numpy as np

def color_sign(x):
    c = colorama.Fore.GREEN if x > 0 else colorama.Fore.RED
    return f'{c}{x}'

np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': color_sign})
```

Note that this is a global config and will print all arrays with this convention.

Comment: It works! And I just add `print('\033[0m')` at the end of the program to restore the default console color.

Comment: You could simply use `colorama.Fore.RESET`, which will work on other platforms as well.

Comment: Yeah that looks better

Answer (score 1):

I think [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) is a good way to do this :

```
from colorama import fore

print(f'{fore.Green}green color')
```